# Best way of bulk inserting a list of records in DuckDB using DuckDB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, duckdb

#### Context

I'm working with the awesome [DuckDB.NET](https://github.com/Giorgi/DuckDB.NET) library and C# for
this example. I'm specifically working with the ADO.NET provider.

#### Problem

My database contains the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl01 (
    Id INTEGER,
    TextListTest TEXT[],
    DateTest DATE
);
```

In the program each record is encapsulated by a class:

```cs
class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> TextListTest { get; set; };
    public DateTime TextListTest { get; set; };
}
```

and is appended to a `List<Record>`. This list gets
very large so I would like to avoid the per-row overhead of `INSERT` statements in a
loop. The [documentation](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/insert) says that if I absolutely must use
inserts in this manner I should also wrap them in calls of `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`. I
really don't want to miss out on insert performance here. Is there another approach I can use with
the library I'm using?

I noticed in the [DuckDB.NET
sample](https://github.com/Giorgi/DuckDB.NET/blob/main/DuckDB.NET.Samples/Program.cs) with the
`LowLevelBindingsSample()` method that I could use prepared statements but I'm not sure that if that would confer any performance benefits.

Is there an approach I'm missing - perhaps the [appender](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/appender)? If someone could provide an example using the 3 specific data
types in the above table that would be greatly appreciated (I'm having trouble figuring out the
`LIST` column).

```cs
using DuckDB.NET.Data;

namespace DuckTest;

class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> TextListTest { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTest { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // pretend this is a really big list!
        List<Record> recordList = new List<Record>
        {
            new Record { Id = 1, TextListTest = new List<string> { "Ball", "Horse" }, DateTest = new DateTime(1994, 12, 3) },
            new Record { Id = 2, TextListTest = new List<string> { "Matthew", "Giorgi is cool!" }, DateTest = new DateTime(1998, 11, 28) },
            new Record { Id = 3, TextListTest = new List<string> { "Red", "Black", "Purple" }, DateTest = new DateTime(1999, 9, 13) },
            new Record { Id = 4, TextListTest = new List<string> { "Cat" }, DateTest = new DateTime(1990, 2, 5) },
        };

        using (var duckDBConnection = new DuckDBConnection("Data Source=db01.duckdb"))
        {
            duckDBConnection.Open();

            var command = duckDBConnection.CreateCommand();

            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tbl01 ( Id INTEGER, TextListTest TEXT[], DateTest DATE );";
            var executeNonQuery = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // I could do this in a loop but there's probably a better way...
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl01 VALUES (1, ['Ball', 'Horse'], '1994-12-03');";
            executeNonQuery = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I would be willing to use the low level bindings library if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library has [support for appenders](https://github.com/Giorgi/DuckDB.NET/blob/main/DuckDB.NET/NativeMethods.cs#L196) so that should be the fastest way to import data.

Comment: Seems the file location has changed https://github.com/Giorgi/DuckDB.NET/blob/main/DuckDB.NET.Bindings/NativeMethods/NativeMethods.Appender.cs

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Yes, the location has changed. There is now a managed wrapper around the appended for a better API.